# How to Update player slider handle current value by AVAudioPlayer current time

Tags: ios, swift

Now I'm using the `MSCircularSlider` library as a Cocoapod. Its `slider.value` is `slider.currentValue` and when I try to do simple `UISlider` (try to equal `slider.value` to `player.currentTime`), it's working well, but when I try to do it in `CircularSlider`, the handle is not moving to the `AVAudioPlayer.currentTime`.

How to solve it?

Please, help me!

```
let player = AVAudioPlayer()

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionCell

    print("tapped")

        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: songsData[indexPath.row].name, withExtension: "mp3") else { return }


        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: .mixWithOthers)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.mp3.rawValue)

        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    player.prepareToPlay()
    timerLabel.text = String(player.currentTime)
    slider.alpha = 1
    slider.maximumValue = Float(player.duration)
    slider.currentValue = 0.0

    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    player.play()
}

@objc func updateTime(_ timer: Timer) {
    let currentTime = player.currentTime
    var elapsedTime: TimeInterval = currentTime
    let minutes = UInt8(elapsedTime / 60.0)
    elapsedTime -= (TimeInterval(minutes) * 60)
    let seconds = UInt8(elapsedTime)
    elapsedTime -= TimeInterval(seconds)
    let strMinutes = String(format: "%02d", minutes)
    let strSeconds = String(format: "%02d", seconds)
    timerLabel.text = "\(strMinutes):\(strSeconds)"
    timer.invalidate()
    self.slider.currentValue = Float(self.player.currentTime)
    timer.invalidate()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `updateTime(_:)` code invalidates your timer. (Twice!) I would expect it to fire once after .01 seconds, then never again, and as a result you probably won't see a visible change in the slider value.

Get rid of the calls to `timer.invalidate()` except when the sound is finished playing.

I haven't used that particular framework before so I don't know for sure if it works as you're using it but a quick glance at the README file suggests that you are.

On another note, `Timer` objects are a little crude, and have a resolution of about 0.02 seconds at best, so a timer with an interval of 0.01 seconds isn't likely to fire that often. Also, the refresh rate on iOS device screens is 1/60th of a second, so there's no point in trying to update the screen more often than that.

If you really need smooth drawing that updates on every screen update you should look at using a `CADisplayLink` timer, but for something as simple as this a timer interval of 1/30 of a second or so should be fine.

Comment: I deleted timer.invalidate() and change Timer interval to 0.02, but without timer.invalidate() player is not working and slider is not changing. Can you explain how to use CADisplayLink timer in my example, please?